# Is setting the ownership / permission for /etc/apache2 to have the group ownership `adm` and chmod g+w "safe"?

Tags: linux, permissions, apache2

Good morning.
I'm daring to ask my first ever qestion here.
I'm annoyed having to use sudo all the time to modify the apache config files - mostly when I use the Remote SSH feature of my editor, then I can't use sudo anyway (or can I?) -.-

So I was thinking in just `chgrp -R adm /etc/apache2` and giving `chmod -R g+w` on e.g. sites-enabled/

I'm the only user on this mashine. How are you handeling this stuff? Is my thonght going in a good direction, or is there a reason why the permissions are not already set this way? Are there other concerns that I'm not seeing right now?

I hope this question is not too stupid and I didn't overlook the perfect answer that's already there.
Thaks in advance!

Comment: nope don't do that, if annoyed about using sudo, either du `sudo su - root` which give you the root shell, or make it password less but I would not suggesting that you change the ownership

Comment: @djdomi: or simply `sudo -i`

Comment: okay esa, i am oldschool administrator, so i had to login with a unpriv user and su up myself, thats why i am mostly unaware about the whole sudo thing

Comment: @djdomi that `sudo -i` thing is 23 years old and `sudo -s` existed from 1995.

Comment: Thanks guys. My "problem" only is, that when I go in over a gui thingy like VS Code using my regular user (I dont think ssh'ing in as root is such a good idea either) I have no way of executing sudo when I need it e.g. when I hit the save button. I guess then I'm just sticking to good old nano directly over ssh.. 

Anyway thanks alot for the answers and saving me from evil ;-)

Comment: I just fond my solution. I think I was just looking at the wront end 
 -.- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yy0931.save-as-root Sorry guys